# Suggestion to improve my Powershell script to update a clone folder with the latest content from master

Tags: git, powershell, tfs, devops

Wanted to ask the community about the approach I am taking here to update a the clone folder from a master.

I have two folders

1. The master folder which is a TFS(Azure Dev Opps) bound solution.
2. The clone of the master but Github is the repo.

My master folder  is a 'TFS solution' it lives in its own ecosystem and has its own internal users, as for the clone 'Github' it has its own users that are external and has its own ecosystem.

With this script what I am aiming to do is keep the clone repo current with the latest changes to the master.

**Master Makes a change ----> Clone File the change happens gets updated**

Its important that I do not blindly cut and paste the whole folder from master to clone every time I make a change, Here is the script that I made, it works well for now but I wanted to know if there was any holes in my logic, Thanks .

```
#Create path variables
$olddir = "C:\Data\Master"
$newdir = "C:\Users\Clone"


#Get the list of files in oldFolder
$oldfiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $olddir | Where-Object {-not ($_.PSIsContainer)}

#get the list of files in new folder
$newfiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $newdir | Where-Object {-not ($_.PSIsContainer)}

Compare-Object $newfiles $oldfiles  -Property LastWriteTime -Passthru | sort LastWriteTime | foreach {

     $fl = (($_.Fullname).ToString().Replace("$olddir","$newdir")) 
     $dir = Split-Path $fl

  if ($fl  -notlike '*\obj\Release\*'){
     if( $_.Fullname -ne $fl){
               If (!(Test-Path $dir)){
                  mkdir $dir
                }
            copy-item $_.Fullname $fl -Force 
            Write-Host "From to --> " $_.Fullname "TO --> " $fl
        }}
}
```

Comment: What about `robocopy` and the mirror `/mir` option ?

Comment: @LotPings Could you provide an example use case for this that you could recommend? I am not familiar with robocopy, Thanks!

Comment: @LotPings I was looking for an answer that is more specific than google, if you are an expert I would appreciate you sharing some knowledge.

Comment: I'd start with `robocopy "C:\Data\Master" "C:\Users\Clone" * /mir /XD "\obj\Release" /L` the /L will only log what would be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty solid to me. Is there any way to natively sync a Git Repo with TFS? I don't have any TFS experience..

Another way you could handle this is by zipping up the contents of `C:\Users\Clone\*.*` to a timestamped file (ex: *OldFiles_changed_01_01_2018_10_42_am.zip*) and just copy over the newly modified repo - this way you have historical copies in `C:\Users\Clone\` of each change made.. (although, that is kind of redundant since you're using Git on the front end)

As far as "best practices" - which tends to essentially just mean 'security' these days - it looks good to me. As far as "in practice" - it's really what works best for your scenario.. If you dont need *.zip backups each time there is a change, then your original script looks solid.

Comment: thanks for the suggesting to make a backup, Really ideal solution would be two way (Master ---> clone) and (clone ---> Master) solution when an update happens. Still looking tho!

Comment: Yea this one sounds like a tough scenario! If I were you, I would focus my research on some native way to sync Git/TFS and vice versa. Cheers!

Comment: Also, `robocopy` is clunky and not what you're looking for.  You may be better off looking into some third party tool that syncs files - like DirSync Pro:

https://www.dirsyncpro.org/